# Delete Android subscription listing via Google Play Developer API

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

I want to remove a 12 month subscription option from our Android app so it is not available for users to purchase any more. I am happy for users that currently have that subscription to continue with it to the end.

I know you cannot disable subscriptions from the Google Play Dashboard, but is it possible via the REST API?

I see via the Inappproducts end point there is a delete method (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/inappproducts/delete), however is this available for subscriptions? More importantly what happens to users that currently have that subscription?

The Purchases:subscriptions method has a cancel subscription method, but this wont remove the subscription from sale within the app.

Comment: Can't you release an update for your app without the subscription option? Don't delete subscription from the google play account, else existing users will not remain subscribed to it as the product won't be available

Comment: Yes we can and something we will look to do. The issue is we are then in the hands of users updating to the latest version which could take a while and people can still purchase the subscription until they update. With Apple you can set 'Cleared for sale' to 'no' for an in-app purchase which removes it as a purchase option, but still honours the subscription to those that already have it. I wish there was something similar on Google Play.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it is possible in Android - else it would have been visible on the dashboard, and you won't have to use API. I checked the API - it doesn't have a disable option - delete will I guess cause problems for already subscribed users

Comment: Thanks for the help. Agree it doesn't look possible :(

Answer (score 0):

I am currently removing subscriptions using the PHP library

```
$GPService->purchases_subscriptions->revoke("com.app.identifier","subscription_product_id","purchase_unique_token_per_user");
```

From my experience this can have an error and revoke it after a few days or doesn't have an error and removes it immediately or then again after a few days.

Comment: what php library ? can you give an example ? regards